# Subir Imagen mediante ajax jquery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buen dia amigos, necesito saber como puedo subir imagenes con jquery ajax en php tengo este es mi script

```
$(document).ready( function() {   // Esta parte del código se ejecutará automáticamente cuando la página esté lista.
            $("#sucursalbutton").click( function() {

                if(validarSucursal()){                               // Primero validará el formulario.
                    $.post("/Controllers/SucursalController.php", $("#sucursaldata").serialize(), function(res){
                        if(res == 1){
                            toastr.success('El Cliente se dio de alta correctamente.', {timeOut: 5000, progressBar: true});
                            $('#clientedata').trigger("reset");
                        } else {
                            toastr.error('Error al registrar el cliente.', {timeOut: 5000, progressBar: true});
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

y este es mi HTML

```
<div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">Dar de alta Clientes</h5>
                            <div class="position-relative form-group">
                                <div>
                                    <form id="sucursaldata" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                                            <label for="nombresucursal" class="">Nombre de la Sucursal</label>
                                            <input name="nombresucursal" id="nombresucursal" placeholder="Nombre de la Sucursal" type="text" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                                            <label for="imagensuc" class="">Imagen</label>
                                            <input name="imagensuc" id="imagensuc" type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="mt-1 btn btn-primary" id="sucursalbutton" type="button">Enviar</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

al momento de hacer un `var_dump` no me envia la imagen

Comment: Y que es lo que te muestra en `var_dump`???

Comment: Cuando valido con $_FILES, esto: array(0) {
}  .............. Cuando valido con $_POST solo el campo nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que cambies tu metodo `$.post()` por `$.ajax()` para que pases el parametro `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` el cual es para mandar archivos.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controllers/SucursalController.php", 
    data: $("#sucursaldata").serialize(), 
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
}).done(function(res){
    if(res == 1){
        toastr.success('El Cliente se dio de alta correctamente.', {timeOut: 5000, progressBar: true});
        $('#clientedata').trigger("reset");
    } else {
        toastr.error('Error al registrar el cliente.', {timeOut: 5000, progressBar: true});
    }
});
```

Prueba y comenta si te funciono.

Comment: el contentType, aunque este definido arriba en el formulario debo definirlo en el script tambien?